# extract values from array of objects where values are the same Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

How can I create an array containing the values of people that have the same office

```
const arr = [
  { "officeID": "1", "people": 10},
  { "officeID": "2", "people": 10 },
  { "officeID": "1", "people": 20 }
]
```

The intented outcome should be an array[10,20] containing the values of people that have the same office id

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you count the total people in each office as you want to merge.

```js
const arr = [
  { officeID: '1', people: 10 },
  { officeID: '2', people: 40 },
  { officeID: '1', people: 20 },
];

let ret = arr.reduce((prev, c) => {
  const p = prev;
  if (!p[c.officeID]) p[c.officeID] = [c.people];
  else p[c.officeID] = [...p[c.officeID], c.people];
  return p;
}, {});

ret = Object.entries(ret).map((x) => ({ officeID: x[0], people: x[1] }));
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: const arr = [
  { officeID: "1", people: 10 },
  { officeID: "2", people: 40 },
  { officeID: "1", people: 20 },
];

The intended outcome would be an array [10,20] . These are the values of people that have the same office.

Comment: Do you want group the same office people as an array like [{ officeID: "1", people: [10, 20] }, { officeID: "2", people: [40] }].

Comment: yes exactly @mr hr

Comment: @StLoiz now check it. I have updated the code according to your requirement.